# perl6 Hash key <$/[0]> , <"$/[0]"> and {"$/[0]"} make the values behave differently

Tags: hash, key, quote, raku

I have a file in the format of `type : amount` and I want to put all
the lines into a hash whose keys are the *`types`* and the values are
the sum of the *`amounts`*.

However, it seems that how the *`types`* are quoted affects how the
*`amounts`* behave. Can someone explain how so?

Here is the contents of file `data`:

```
food :  100.01
gas  :  50.02
food :  20.03
gas  :  30.04
```

When the keys are constructed with  `%x<$/[0]>` , the keys seem to be
correct, but the values seem to be pushed into an array, even though I
want to add to get the total amount:

```
home/lisprog$  cat data | perl6 -ne '
    state %x //= {}; 
    if $_ ~~ m/ \s* (\S+) \s* \: \s* (\d+\.\d+) \s* / {
        if %x<$/[0]>:exists {
            %x<$/[0]> += ($/[1].Numeric); 
        } 
        else { 
            %x.push: "$/[0]"=>($/[1].Numeric); 
        } 
    }; 
    END { for %x.kv -> $m, $n { say "$m : $n"; } }' | sort
food : 100.01 20.03
gas : 50.02 30.04
```

The same behavior if the keys are constructed with `<"$/[0]">` :

```
cat data | perl6 -ne '
    state %x //= {}; 
    if $_ ~~ m/ \s* (\S+) \s* \: \s* (\d+\.\d+) \s* / {
        if %x<"$/[0]">:exists {
            %x<"$/[0]"> += ($/[1].Numeric); 
        } 
        else { 
            %x.push: "$/[0]"=>($/[1].Numeric); 
        } 
    }; 
    END { for %x.kv -> $m, $n { say "$m : $n"; } }' | sort
food : 100.01 20.03
gas : 50.02 30.04
```

When the keys are constructed with `%x{"$/[0]"}`, the keys and values
behave correctly:

```
home/lisprog$  cat data | perl6 -ne '
    state %x //= {}; 
    if $_ ~~ m/ \s* (\S+) \s* \: \s* (\d+\.\d+) \s* / {
        if %x{"$/[0]"}:exists {
            %x{"$/[0]"} += ($/[1].Numeric); 
        } 
        else { 
            %x.push: "$/[0]"=>($/[1].Numeric); 
        } 
    }; 
    END { for %x.kv -> $m, $n { say "$m : $n"; } }' | sort
food : 120.04
gas : 80.06
```

So, how come the keys affect how values behave? Or did I ask a wrong question?

Answer (score 3):

I think you have a misconception about what `<>` does.  They're basically the equivalent of **single** quotes:

```
say <"foo">    # "foo"
```

So you're checking if a key '$/[0]' exists, which it doesn't, and then `push` a `Pair` onto the hash with the correct double quoted (although unnecessary to quote it there), which *will* create the correct key if it doesn't exist yet.

Since `$0` is short for `$/[0]`, `m///` uses `$_` by default, and non-existing keys in a hash are silently created with `Any`, and you can `+=` `Any` just like you can in Pumpkin Perl 5, and `END` blocks don't need to have a block, you only really need:

```
$ cat data | perl6 -ne '
state %x; 
%x{$0} += $1 if m/ \s* (\S+) \s* \: \s* (\d+\.\d+) \s* /;
END for %x.kv -> $m, $n { say "$m : $n" }' | sort
```

Actually, come to think of it, the actually smells like a `Mix` (https://docs.raku.org/type/Mix).  Leaving that as an exercise for the reader :-)

Comment: Thank you Elizabeth Mattijsen !! I got it now. My mistake was thinking that <> does double quote with interpolation. And with the hash push that made the right key, I had harder time finding out my own misconception. I will look into the Bags, Mixes, Sets, etc. Thanks !!!